# How get primary keys & values in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use the following code for get primary keys of my entity in EF :

```
 ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_dataContext).ObjectContext;
 ObjectSet<TEntity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
 IList<string> pKeys = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                         .KeyMembers
                                         .Select(k => k.Name).ToList();
```

but my problem is here above code retun only name of primary keys but I need values too

eg : ID,123

so I **must** use reflection for this purpose like this

```
obj[i] = entity.GetType().GetProperty(pKeys[i]).GetValue(entity, null);
```

Is there a way that I **do not use reflection** for get values? (more speed)

Comment: try this IList<string> pKeys = set.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => new { Name = k.Name,ID=k.id}).ToList();

Comment: Not Correct !!! k => new { Name = k.Name,ID=k.id} WHAT ?!!!

Comment: @user3166171 new { Name = k.Name,ID=k.id} is just an anonymous object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb397696.aspx